# Traveling on B1/B2 visa for training

Tags: b1-b2-visas

I currently have a valid B1/B2 visa. I got this visa when I had applied for a visitor/tourist visa, stating the purpose that I'll be visiting US for pleasure. 
Now I need to travel to US for a training and wondering if I can do it legally using B1/B2 visa ?